# Unable to run simple cucumber program with java and Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

**Error in Feature file :**

```
Unimplemented Subset definition
```

**Error when Run Testrunner class**

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Error parsing feature file search.feature
```

I am using Intellij , Created Maven project and setup below code. I have already checked for subset plugin and it seems installed with latest version into intelliJ.

Already tried different answers from other questions on stackoverflow but still unable to run it.

**TestRunner.java**

```
package runner;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/features/",glue={"stepDefinition"})

       public class TestRunner{



    }
```

**SmokeTest.java**

```
package stepDefinition;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

    public class SmokeTest {


        @Given("^I am on the home page$")
        public void iAmOnTheHomePage() throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("1");
        }

        @When("^I select to search for game$")
        public void iSelectToSearchForGame() throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("2");
        }



        @Then("^I get the search results with game names at the top$")
        public void iGetTheSearchResultsWithGameResultsAtTheTop() throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("3");
        }
    }
```

**Feature :**

```
Feature : search

Scenario : Searching as a Global user
   Given I am on the home page
   When I select to search for game
   Then I get the search results with game names at the top
```

**POM.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.demo.cucumber</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is from `Substeps IntelliJ Plugin` that IntelliJ suggests you install when it locates a `.feature` file inside your project.

Just ignore this extension when it pops up or uninstall it if you already have it.

`Cucumber for Java` and `Gherkin` should be enough. Let me know if it works out.

Comment: ok now I have uninstall Substeps IntelliJ plugin, Restarted Intellij and run program. Getting error : `cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Error parsing feature file search.feature`

Comment: In your feature file, remove the spacing between `Feature` and `:`. Same for `Scenario`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have read and tried more than 25 solutions from internet but no one told or suggest me what you did here. Issue resolved.